# Generalisation of "discrete" and "indiscrete" left/right adjoint to the forgetful functor for general "ordered" Categories with monotone. morphisms.

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, order-theory, lattice-orders, galois-connections

The following is taken from "An introduction to Category Theory" by Harold Simmons

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Example (Galois connection):}$   We modify the category of $\textbf{Pos}$(Poset) to produce a new category $\textbf{Pos}^{\vdash}.$  As with $\textbf{Pos},$ the objects of $\textbf{Pos}^{\vdash}.$ are posets, but the arrows are different.

Given a pair $S,T$ of posets, an $\mathrm{adjunction}$ from $S$ to $T$ is a pair of monotone maps as on the left such that the equivalence on the right

$$S\substack{
\xrightarrow{f}\\
\xleftarrow[g]\\}T\quad\quad f(a)\leq b \text{ iff } a\leq g(b)$$

holds for all $a\in S$ and $b\in T.$  We call

$$f\text{ the left adjoint }\quad\quad g\text{ the right adjoint }$$

of the pair, and sometimes write

$$f\dashv g$$

to indicate an adjunction.

$\textbf{(1) Exercise:}$  Each set $S$ can be converted into a preset (pre-order set) in two extreme ways.  The discrete version uses equality as the comparison.  For the indiscrete version any two  elements are comparable.  Show that the forgetful functor

$$\textbf{Set}\leftarrow \textbf{Pre}$$

has both a left and a right adjoint, and these are different.

$\textit{Solution:}$  Consider the forgetful functor

$\textbf{Set}\xleftarrow{U} \textbf{Pre}$

We produce a left adjoint and a right adjoint to this functor:

$$D\vdash U\quad\quad \small\textbf{Set}\substack{
\xrightarrow{D}\\
\xleftarrow{U}\\
\xrightarrow[I]\\}\small\textbf{Pre}\quad\quad U\vdash I$$

Each set $X$ $\color{blue}{can}$ $\color{blue}{be}$ $\color{blue}{converted}$ $\color{blue}{into}$ a preset $\color{blue}{in}$ $\color{blue}{extreme}$ $\color{blue}{ways}$

$$DX=(X,=)\quad\quad IX=(X,\parallel)$$

On the left we use equality as the comparison.  This gives a poset.  On the right any two elements are comparable.  This is not a poset if $X$ has least two elements.  We call these the |

$$\mathrm{discrete}\quad\quad\mathrm{indiscrete}$$

presets....

$\textbf{(2) Exercise:}$ Show that the forgetful functor

$$\textbf{Set}\leftarrow \textbf{Top}$$

has both a left and a right adjoint, and these are different.

$\textit{Solution:}$ This is more or less the same as solution of the previous exercise except we now use topologies rather than pre-orders.

Let

$$\textbf{Set}\leftarrow \textbf{Top}$$

to be the forgetful functor.  We product a left adjoint and a right adjoint to this functor.

$$\small\textbf{Set}\substack{
\xrightarrow{D}\\
\xleftarrow{U}\\
\xrightarrow[I]\\}\small\textbf{Top}$$

Each set $X$ $\color{blue}{can}$ $\color{blue}{be}$ $\color{blue}{converted}$ $\color{blue}{into}$ a topological space $\color{blue}{in}$ $\color{blue}{extreme}$ $\color{blue}{ways}.$

$$DX=(X,PX)\quad\quad IX=(X,\{\emptyset, X\})$$

On the left we use discrete topology in which each subset is open.  On the right we use the indiscrete topology in which only the two extreme subsets are open.  Naturally we call these the

$$\mathrm{discrete}\quad\quad\mathrm{indiscrete}$$

space...

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In the solutions for the above two questions for finding the left and right adjoints, Simmons stated that "Each set $X$ $\color{blue}{can}$ $\color{blue}{be}$ $\color{blue}{converted}$ $\color{blue}{into}$ $...$ $\color{blue}{in}$ $\color{blue}{extreme}$ $\color{blue}{ways}.$"  In the case of question 1, it is for pre-order sets, and for question 2, it is for topological spaces.  Am I right to assume that for any objects in a category where there is order set kind of structure, in the sense of objects that can be compared like in a pre-order or partial order, and that can also be formed into a lattice/complete lattice, (As a result, the morphisms in the category have to be monotone. This is only a guess on my part) then I can take the discrete and indiscrete version of those objects for left and right adjoints respectively?  I know for the case of the forgetful functor sending posets to sets, the notion of galois connections ($\textbf{Example}$ above) come into it for adjunction. How does that related to the solutions of the two questions above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are we defining preset? "Set without equality relation" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @FShrike preset is pre-ordered set, reflexive and transitive.  I edited my question to make it more clear.  Sorry I thought "Preset" is a common term in math parlance.

Comment: Looking up ‘preset’ gave me only very strange foundational stuff. What you’re looking for I have seen called ‘pr**o**set’ instead. Or preorder

Comment: @FShrike I thought preorder and proset meant the same.

Comment: yes... that's the point?

Comment: Now that I've read your question in full, it seems like the main point of the question is to ask if this phenomenon (discrete and indiscrete adjoints to the forgetful functor) admits a generalisation. So (maybe, I suggest) you could focus more on that and remove superfluous context such as the 'solutions' (they are very terse and don't address the exercise properly imo but *anyway*) to those exercises, since these are just making the question longer and tricking the reader (until the end) into thinking you're asking something else

Comment: @FShrike I included the relevant sections of both solutions for background context.  I don't think Simmons text is well known. Also, I probably would have articulated the way you stated but I am still not fluent in asking questions in category theory. I highlighted the portion that I did not understand and also I want to know if this is some sort of generalizations.  Anyways, would you happen to know anything about the matter?

Comment: Though the text might not be well-known, the fact that these adjoints exist is well-known and a classic exercise. I wouldn't know how to answer this question, it seems like some kind of universal algebra thing. You need some kind of generalisation of the concept of a category of "ordered" objects (topological spaces can be associated with their poset of opens) and I wouldn't know how to formulate that. It might involve a category of categories.

Comment: @FShrike do I need to make a repost of this question.  Also, would anyone on here know about this question?  Or should I ask on math overflow?

Comment: nono don't repost. This should be fine here. I just recommend refocusing it. You're free to edit as much or as little as you please

Comment: @FShrike I added more info to my post, is it a bit more clear?

Comment: I personally don't think adding the 'example' of a Galois connection or more text about the 'solutions' is relevant/clear but that's just one man's opinion. A tldr at the top of the question could be helpful, maybe

Comment: I think you're looking for the notion of a "discrete object" which generalizes this (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+object).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so a lot of free-forgetful functors for different categories, relating to adjoint functors fall under this topic?  Is there a reference for beginners of category theory where they can consult, with a slow down in introducing all the new math terms.

Comment: This is not really a beginner topic. It's not a very common condition and most interesting examples don't satisfy it. I wouldn't worry too much about this for now.

Comment: @QiaochYuan what kind of categories would have objects where I can put an order on it and form complete lattices like in the case of pre-order sets and topological spaces?  I probably am getting the misimpression that a lot of examples for finding left or right adjoint can be done like the two examples above?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan also what does Simmons mean by "each set X can be converted into ________ in extreme ways."  Then he throws out their respective discrete and indiscrete presets/topological spaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan another thing is that the solutions to the above exercises, it literally bypasses the process of having to finding free objects for the case of left adjoints of a forgetful functor.  That is the reasons why I am posting the question.

Comment: It is just an intuitive way to describe the left and right adjoints. Intuitively they are the "biggest" and "smallest" topologies / orders (although which one is "bigger" and which one is "smaller" depends on the direction you compare topologies / orders). I don't understand what you mean by "literally bypasses the process of having to find free objects."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771925/when-is-the-unit-map-eta-for-a-free-object-an-epimorphism/4772124?noredirect=1#comment10137689_4772124) here which you replied to.  In it, I quoted the definition of what a free object is with respect to the forgetful functor.  In the case of Top, and given a forgetful functor sending Top to Set,...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ...I am suppose to find what the free object over Set is with respect to that forgetful functor in order to show the existence of left adjoint functor.  Well that free object over Set is suppose to be the discrete topology.  But in Simmons exercise, he basically tells me I can just compare the different presets/topologies to find out that it is the discrete topology.  In the case of preset, we get the poset.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan how come Simmons can just did what he did to find the left adjoint of Top without showing what the free object is according to the other post which you replied in.  My understanding is to show the existence of left adjoint, you figure out what a free object is and show that it satisfies the definition from my other post.  Simmons seems to just did something entirely different, sort of like some sort of math version of magical shortcut.

Comment: Simmons is telling you what the free and the cofree objects are.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan under what circumstances can his methods be generalize to other categories and forgetful functors?

Comment: This is the subject of the nLab page I linked to (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+object) which gives several classes of examples. But, again, personally I would say don't worry about it for now. This is a very specific type of example and most examples of left and right adjoints don't look like this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ah kk.  thank you for clearing this up for me.  I thought his methods can be applied to other categories where its objects can be ordered, then something similar can be done

Comment: There are similar constructions that can be done e.g. for various categories of graphs. But I'm not aware of a really clean general statement, and personally I've never wanted or needed one.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ah kk.  Thank you for telling me that.  I will keep it in mind.